# Why change in one list affect other list?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have two List collection.

`List<list<int>> FS = new List<List<int>>();List<List<int> V= new List<List<int>>()`

I added some some valuse to `FS`

Now My `FS` Look Like

```
FS={{1},{2},{3}}
```

Then i assigned valus of `FS` to `V` `V = FS`
Now i want to go through each pair

```
//Performing some Logic 
for (int i = 0; i < FS.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < FS.Count; k++)
            {
                List<int> temp = new List<int>();
                temp.AddRange(FS[i]);
                temp.AddRange(FS[k]);
                VF.Add(IP_CFFM(temp));
                V.Add(temp);
                if (IP_CFFM(temp) > IP_CFFM(FS[i]) && IP_CFFM(temp) > IP_CFFM(FS[k]))
                {
                   FS[i].AddRange(FS[k]);
                   FS.Remove(FS[k]);

                }
            }
        }
```

Before executing `if(condition)`  `V` will Look Like `V = {{1},{2},{3},{1,2}}`
But after executing the line `FS[i].AddRange(FS[k]);` List V is changed and it look like  `{{1,2},{2},{3},{1,2}}` Within the `if(condition)`, i am not manipulation or not performing anything on `V`. Then why it happens?

Comment: Class is always a reference type, please go through [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is a class, so it is reference.

`V = FS` actually mean both pointing to same location/address space.

This means that anything you do to it will be reflected in the other. It is just that two ***different*** names for your `List`

Comment: So how i can avoid it? My desired output executing the first if loop  is { {1},{2},{3},{1,2} } @Hari Prasad

Comment: Instead of V= FS i tried foreach (List<int> Fi in FS)
        {
            V.Add(Fi);
        } but also same effect @Hari Prasad

Comment: I was out for a while, you can actually  use `V= FS.ToList();` it creates new list with the Data of FS.

Comment: I cant access   FS.Dump(); What it means?  @Hari Prasad

Comment: This is an `Extension` that dumps the object data, we _don't_ use this in general coding, instead we can loop through collection and print data.